# How to fix font width independent of font style?

Tags: html, css

There is a horizontal menu:

```
<ul>
  <li>Text</li>
  <li>Text 2</li>
</ul>
```

When a user clicks over one of the li, it's font-weight becomes bold. Therefore, the width of the li element is a bit changed. As a result, the menu jumps.

How to fix the independent width of text?

Comment: Please could you show any relevant styling that you have already? E.g. are you using flex or grid or float or….

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `:before` pseudo-element with `font-weight: 700;` and `content: attr(data-text);`:

```css
ul{
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
  row-gap: 8px;
}

ul li {
  position: relative;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

ul li:before {
  content: attr(data-text);
  font-weight: 700;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .4s;
}

ul li span {
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  transition: opacity .4s;
}

ul li:hover span {
  opacity: 0;
}

ul li:hover:before {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li data-text="Text">
    <span>Text</span>
  </li>
  <li data-text="Text 2">
    <span>Text 2</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This is the best answer here, but could even be better. There is no need change the opacity on hover and show two different elements. If you set height to `0` on the `::before` and give it `overflow: hidden` and make sure it isn’t read by a screen reader, you’ll have a simpler solution. It will not make the menu jump, and it will really just used one element. See this on [CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/bold-on-hover-without-the-layout-shift/). Right now, your menu double announces on a screen reader. This would fix that.

Comment: Thanks for the comment and link to the article. `height: 0;` is an interesting idea.